# Create group ID, using values from two columns - transitive

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataset of products with two columns representing classifications. I would like to obtain a group id based membership to a sub-graph.

The group id has to be transitive in the sense that if class1 is the same for observations 1 and 2, and class2 is equal for 2 and 3, then 1,2, and 3 are equal. In the example, you can see transitivity working in the result where rows 1-4 have the same group_id.

I am working in a sql-warehouse in snowflake.

Input:

```
| class_1 | class_2           |
---------|-------------------
|       A |                L1 |
|       A |                L1 |
|       B |                L1 |
|       B |                L2 |
|       C |                L3 |
|       D |                L4 |
+---------+-------------------+
```

Output:

```
| class_1 | class_2           |group_id|
---------|-------------------|-------|
|       A |                L1 |     1 |
|       A |                L1 |     1 |
|       B |                L1 |     1 |
|       B |                L2 |     1 |
|       C |                L3 |     2 |
|       D |                L4 |     3 |
+---------+-------------------+-------+
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
    ,sum(edge) over (order by id) + 1 as group_id
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,iff(class_1 = lag(class_1,1,class_1)over(order by id),0,1) as c1_t
        ,iff(class_2 = lag(class_2,1,class_2)over(order by id),0,1) as c2_t
        ,iff(c1_t+c2_t > 1,1,0) as edge
    FROM (
      VALUES(1,'A', 'L1')
      ,(2,'A', 'L1')
      ,(3,'B', 'L1')
      ,(4,'B', 'L2')
      ,(5,'C', 'L3')
      ,(6,'D', 'L4')
    ) AS v(id, class_1, class_2)
)
```

gives:

```
ID   CLASS_1    CLASS_2  C1_T   C2_T    EDGE    GROUP_ID
1    A          L1       0      0       0       1
2    A          L1       0      0       0       1
3    B          L1       1      0       0       1
4    B          L2       0      1       0       1
5    C          L3       1      1       1       2
6    D          L4       1      1       1       3
```